# Moshe, Israel entry

Tags: eretz-yisrael, moshe-rabbeinu

HaShem tells Moshe Rabbeinu that he will not be allowed into Eretz Ha-Kodesh. Moshe Rabbeinu is shown the Eretz Ha-Kodesh will standing on the banks of the river Jordan ( or somewhere in that area marked by the red line in the picture below). But isn't that red lined area also part of Eretz Ha-Kodesh? Sheveth Gad etc lived in that area.

[image]

Comment: this is likely a question with a very obvious answer, but as a goy (raised Christian) I'd always thought the Jordan was the border, what's the source for the red line as the border?

Comment: The red line was the assumed location of Moshe Rabbeinu when he was shown a glimpse of Eretz Yisrael by HaShem. The question was, if the area east of the Jordan river was settled by the tribes of Gad etc., that means that eastern area was also part of Eretz Yisrael. If so, Moshe Rabbeinu was already in Eretz Yisrael! That was what was my question. Seems like there are 2 levels of Eretz Yisrael....one on the west of the Jordan river and one on the east of the Jordan river.

Comment: If the Jordan river was the border and that's where the border of Eretz Yisrael ends, then shevet Gad etc. who were living on the eastern side of the Jordan river would not be living in Eretz Yisrael proper. ( Shevet Gad etc lived in the areas known  today as Amman, Irbid, Zarqa etc )

Comment: ah ok, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 6):

Rashi brings in the beginning of Parshas Vaetchanan (from the sifri in parshas pinchas) that Moshe thought that maybe your question is accurate, and Hashem rescinded his decree and was letting him enter into the land of Israel. There, the Maharal in [Gur Aryeh](https://www.sefaria.org/Gur_Aryeh_on_Devarim.3.23.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains the following to answer how Moshe could enter the land of Gad :

ומה שבא משה אל ארץ סיחון ועוג, אף על גב שגם היא בכלל הארץ אשר נתן הקדוש ברוך הוא לאברהם, היינו טעמא, שעדיין לא שאלו בני ראובן ובני גד הארץ לחלקם, ואם לא [היו] מבקשים את ארץ סיחון ועוג – לא היו יורשים בני ישראל הארץ, כמו שכתב הרמב"ן בפרשת חקת (במדבר כא, כא), וכן הארכנו בפרשת מטות (במדבר פל"ב אות יב), עיין שם, אלא היתה הארץ נשארת חריבה מאין יושב, והיו מניחין אותה כך, והולכין להם. לכך לא יקרא בזה "לא תביאו את הקהל אל הארץ אשר נשבעתי לאבותם" (ר' במדבר כ, יב), כיון שלא היה כבוש הראשון לנחול הארץ ולישב בה

He explains that since if Gad did not ask for this land, it would not be part of Israel, as he quotes from the Ramban. Hence it was not included when Hashem told Moshe that he would not enter the land promised to his forefathers, as this was not included in that oath, as it would not necessarily become part of Israel.